# render jsf commandLink on basis of bean value

Tags: jsf

Hi as per my requirement I have a datatable and last column is activate/deactivate.
I have to create a commandLink for deactivate the row, once it get deactivated, activate commandLink should appear.To acheive this I have created two commandLink one for activate and other for deactivate.but problem is that both are appearing same time.How to restrict appearing one at a time. also I have to show these on the basis of statusId(1-active,2-deactive)

```
<h:commandLink id="a" rendered=#{status=1} action="#{bean.activate}"  value="Activate" />
<h:commandLink id="b" rendered=#{status=2} action="#{bean.deactivate}"  value="Deactivate" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

The correct expression would be

```
 <h:commandLink id="a" rendered="#{status == 1}" action="#{bean.activate}"  value="Activate" />
```

`eq` is also a valid operator. Notice also the quotes.

It would have been nicer if it was a boolean property `deactivated` or (`activated`), but that is more a matter of opinion.